# XML Null when getting child node

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing

Null results when trying to access children of the first item. I'm using Google App Scripts.

```
function parseXml() {
  var url = 'https://example.xml';
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();

  var channel = root.getChild('channel');
  var items = channel.getChildren('item');
  Logger.log(items[1].getValue());
  Logger.log(items[1].getChildren())
  Logger.log(items[1].getChild('g:id'))

}
```

Output:

```
5:37:46 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:37:57 PM  Info    09771332150202100001A&C Ainsworth Wines - A&C Ainsworth Wines - 2021
5:37:57 PM  Info    [[Element: <g:id [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:title [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:description [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:link [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:image_link [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:availability [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:price [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:item_group_id [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:brand [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:gender [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:condition [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:google_product_category [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:product_type [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <g:spec [Namespace: http://base.google.com/ns/1.0]/>], [Element: <quantity/>], [Element: <option_values/>]]
5:37:57 PM  Info    null
5:37:58 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Finally, XML example. Sorry, I can't share the source URL.

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
 <item>
  <g:id>09771332140202100001</g:id>
   <g:title>A&C Ainsworth Wines - A&C Ainsworth Wines - 2021</g:title>
   <g:description></g:description>
 </item>
```

Comment: Can you provide the source URL so this can be tested?

Comment: Sorry, I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current issue and your goal are as follows.

- `Logger.log(items[1].getChild('g:id'))` returns `null`.
- You want to retrieve the value from `<g:id>###</g:id>` in `item` by modifying your script.

When I saw your showing XML and your script, in your script, I thought that the namespace is required to be used. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
Logger.log(items[1].getChild('g:id'))
```

#### To:

```
Logger.log(items[1].getChild('id', XmlService.getNamespace("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")))
```

or

```
Logger.log(items[1].getChild('id', XmlService.getNamespace("g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")))
```

or

```
Logger.log(items[1].getChild('id', XmlService.getNamespace("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")).getValue())
```

or

```
Logger.log(items[1].getChild('id', XmlService.getNamespace("g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")).getValue())
```

- Although I'm not sure about your actual XML data and I cannot test this, I thought that in the case of your XML data, `Logger.log(items[1].getChild('id', XmlService.getNamespace("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")).getValue())` might work.

#### Reference:

- [getNamespace(uri)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#getnamespaceuri)

Comment: Thanks. 

Logger.log(items[1].getChild('id', XmlService.getNamespace("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")))

worked perfectly

Comment: @fasito Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.